# submodule to jitpack

Tags: android, android-studio, jitpack

I have a project on GitHub [OmegaIntentBuilder](https://github.com/Omega-R/OmegaIntentBuilder).
Also, I created library from this project on jitpack.io

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.Omega-R:OmegaIntentBuilder:0.0.5'
}
```

The library works, I could import it without any problems. 
But now I've created two java submodules ("annotations", "processor") with code generation.

```
compile project(':annotations')
annotationProcessor project(':processor')
```

How could I import these submodules to jitpack ?? I mean I want to use it like this

```
compile 'com.github.Omega-R:OmegaIntentBuilder.annotations:0.0.5'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.Omega-R:OmegaIntentBuilder.processor:0.0.5'
```

How could I do this?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 6):

here is an example that shows how to do it: https://github.com/jitpack/gradle-modular

To install each module individually use

- `groupId`: `com.github.User.Repo`
- `artifact id`: `module name`
- note that there are only 2 colons: after the group-id and before the version number!

  ```
  compile 'com.github.jitpack.gradle-modular:client:1.1' 
  compile 'com.github.jitpack.gradle-modular:server:1.1'
  ```